# Selenium on windows server 2019

Tags: selenium

I have to run my excel macro which uses selenium on windows server 2019 64 Bit system. I am getting error "Automation Error. The system cannot find the file specified." on Line

```
Set ks = New Selenium.Keys
```

I have downloaded SeleniumBasic 2.0.9.0 from GitHub.
The installation folder C:\Program Files\SeleniumBasic is in Environment Path

My code looks like this

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim ks As Selenium.Keys
Set ks = New Selenium.Keys

Set d = New ChromeDriver
```

I tried downloading .NetFramework 3.5 it says, This version is already a part of OS.

I think i am missing out something.

If someone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does require .Net Framework installed. In order to install on windows server 2019 system, Go to server manager in windows server 2019 and click

1. Add Roles And Features.
2. Select Role base or feature based installations.
3. Select Your server.
4. You will find .NetFramework 3.5 at the top check it.
5. Just click on install below and it will install.